# Solving intersection point of two circles using sympy in python

Tags: python, math, sympy, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection point of two functions, which are in this case circle1 and circle2 with a radius of r. When I try to find the intersection point, it takes Sympy forever to calculate.

Here is an image with the intersection:
[image]

I think this is because there are an infinite number of intersection points, when theta_1 and theta_2 are raised. Thus I guess sympy keeps solving it until infinity.

Unfortunately, `solve` or `solveset` dont allow to solve an equation for two variables within a given a range.

The code I used is:

```
def SYMPY():
    theta_1, theta_2, r = symbols('theta_1, theta_2, r', real=True)
    r = 10
    x1 = r*cos(theta_1) + 5
    x2 = r*cos(theta_2)
    y1 = r*sin(theta_1)
    y2 = r*sin(theta_2)

    test = sp.Eq((x1-x2)+(y1-y2),0)
    ans = sp.solve(test, theta_1, theta_2)
    print(ans)
SYMPY()
```

Does anybody know how to tackle this problem?

I know Sympy also has the circle() method, but I would like to calculate it using the equations above. This is because I have another (large) equation that I would like to solve, that also involves two circles and an intersection point.

Thanks, Mudi :)

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question but the equation you are solving does not represent the intersection of two circles.

Comment: You can use `check=False` to get an answer more quickly from solve

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I have uploaded a screenshot with the intersection points :)

Do I have to edit the code to:
```ans = sp.solve(test, theta_1, theta_2, check = false)
``` ?

Thanks!

Comment: How do I solve the intersection btw, if the code is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To test whether `(x1,y1)` is the same point as `(x2,y2)`, `Eq((x1-x2)+(y1-y2),0)`doesn't do the job.  You need both `Eq(x1,x2)` and `Eq(y1,y2)`. (Note that you shouldn't make `r` a symbolic variable, as you assign a constant to it.  Also note that `(theta_1, theta_2)` should be written as a tuple (or a list)).

For some reason, unclear to me, sympy doesn't find a solution:

```py
from sympy import symbols, sin, cos, Eq, solve

theta_1, theta_2 = symbols('theta_1, theta_2', real=True)
r = 10
x1 = r * cos(theta_1) + 5
x2 = r * cos(theta_2)
y1 = r * sin(theta_1)
y2 = r * sin(theta_2)

test = [Eq(x1, x2), Eq(y1, y2)]
ans = solve(test, (theta_1, theta_2))
print(ans) # [] ???
```

An alternative is to use the direct circle equations. The angles can be found using the arc tangent.

```py
from sympy import symbols, sin, cos, atan2, Eq, solve

x1, y1 = symbols('x1 y1', real=True)
r = 10
xm1, ym1 = 5, 0  # center of the first circle
xm2, ym2 = 0, 0  # center of the second circle
test = [Eq((x1 - xm1) ** 2 + (y1 - ym1) ** 2, r ** 2),
        Eq((x1 - xm2) ** 2 + (y1 - ym2) ** 2, r ** 2), ]
ans = solve(test, (x1, y1))

for xa, ya in ans:
    theta1 = atan2(xa - xm1, ya - ym1)
    theta2 = atan2(xa - xm2, ya - ym2)
    print(f'theta1: {theta1}, (in radians: {theta1.evalf():.6f})')
    print(f'theta2: {theta2}, (in radians: {theta2.evalf():.6f})')
```

This finds two solutions for `(x1, y1)`:

```
[(5/2, -5*sqrt(15)/2),
 (5/2, 5*sqrt(15)/2)]
```

And corresponding angles:

```
theta1: -pi + atan(sqrt(15)/15), (in radians: -2.888912)
theta2: pi - atan(sqrt(15)/15), (in radians: 2.888912)
theta1: -atan(sqrt(15)/15), (in radians: -0.252680)
theta2: atan(sqrt(15)/15), (in radians: 0.252680)
```

Comment: Note that solve doesn't recognise any domain argument (you might be confusing with solveset). Instead solve infers that the domain is reals if the unknowns to be solved for are created with real=True

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I edited the answer and removed the domain.  Do you have an explanation why the version with `sin` and `cos` doesn't find a solution?

Comment: I think that the `solve` function just needs to be improved for this case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from JohanC is good but I thought I'd add that you can actually get the answer in fully general terms for arbitarry symbols if you use Cartesian coordinates rather than polar:

```
In [88]: x1, x2, y1, y2, xi, yi, r = symbols('x1, x2, y1, y2, xi, yi, r', real=True)

In [89]: eq1 = Eq((x1 - xi)**2 + (y1 - yi)**2, r**2)

In [90]: eq2 = Eq((x2 - xi)**2 + (y2 - yi)**2, r**2)

In [91]: solve([eq1, eq2], [xi, yi])
Out[91]: 
⎡⎛                                       ⎛             ____________________________________________
⎢⎜                                       ⎜            ╱  ⎛  2               2     2               2
⎢⎜  2     2     2     2                  ⎜y₁   y₂   ╲╱  -⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ 
⎢⎜x₁  - x₂  + y₁  - y₂  + (-2⋅y₁ + 2⋅y₂)⋅⎜── + ── - ───────────────────────────────────────────────
⎢⎜                                       ⎜2    2                                       ⎛  2        
⎢⎜                                       ⎝                                           2⋅⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅
⎢⎜─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⎢⎜                                                                            2⋅(x₁ - x₂)          
⎣⎝                                                                                                 

_______________________________________________________          ⎞                                 
⎞ ⎛     2     2               2     2               2⎞           ⎟                                 
⎠⋅⎝- 4⋅r  + x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠ ⋅(x₁ - x₂)⎟                                 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟               __________________
       2     2               2⎞                                  ⎟              ╱  ⎛  2            
x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠                                  ⎠  y₁   y₂   ╲╱  -⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ +
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────, ── + ── - ─────────────────────
                                                                    2    2                         
                                                                                                   

                                                                                           ⎞  ⎛    
                                                                                           ⎟  ⎜    
                                                                                           ⎟  ⎜  2 
_________________________________________________________________________________          ⎟  ⎜x₁  
   2     2               2⎞ ⎛     2     2               2     2               2⎞           ⎟  ⎜    
 x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠⋅⎝- 4⋅r  + x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠ ⋅(x₁ - x₂)⎟  ⎜    
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟, ⎜────
              ⎛  2               2     2               2⎞                                  ⎟  ⎜    
            2⋅⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠                                  ⎠  ⎝    

                                   ⎛             __________________________________________________
                                   ⎜            ╱  ⎛  2               2     2               2⎞ ⎛   
    2     2     2                  ⎜y₁   y₂   ╲╱  -⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠⋅⎝- 4
- x₂  + y₁  - y₂  + (-2⋅y₁ + 2⋅y₂)⋅⎜── + ── + ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                   ⎜2    2                                       ⎛  2              
                                   ⎝                                           2⋅⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                        2⋅(x₁ - x₂)                
                                                                                                   

_________________________________________________          ⎞                                       
  2     2               2     2               2⎞           ⎟                                       
⋅r  + x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠ ⋅(x₁ - x₂)⎟                                       
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟               ________________________
 2     2               2⎞                                  ⎟              ╱  ⎛  2               2  
₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠                                  ⎠  y₁   y₂   ╲╱  -⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  +
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────, ── + ── + ───────────────────────────
                                                              2    2                               
                                                                                                   

                                                                                     ⎞⎤
                                                                                     ⎟⎥
                                                                                     ⎟⎥
___________________________________________________________________________          ⎟⎥
   2               2⎞ ⎛     2     2               2     2               2⎞           ⎟⎥
 y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠⋅⎝- 4⋅r  + x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠ ⋅(x₁ - x₂)⎟⎥
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟⎥
        ⎛  2               2     2               2⎞                                  ⎟⎥
      2⋅⎝x₁  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ + x₂  + y₁  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ + y₂ ⎠                                  ⎠⎦
```